# Why ngModelChange is not working properly?

Tags: angular, binding, ngmodel

I'm creating a form where the user selects a date in an input, then the input 'week' automatically calculates the week of the year of respective date. I'm doing this:

```
[ngModel]="maintenance.date |  date:'w'"  (ngModelChange)="maintenance.week = $event.target.value"
```

the output: maintenance.week = 0

maintenance.date  has the date selected in previous date input. but, as you can see, this doesn't work.

What does works is if I change (ngModelChange) for (mouseenter) but it's not the best way because the user has to pass the mouse over the input 'week' element in order for this to work:

```
[ngModel]="maintenance.date |  date:'w'"  (mouseenter)="maintenance.week = $event.target.value"
```

output: maintenance.week = 48 <- this is the correct week for date: 11/24/2020

Hope you can help me.

Comment: instead of sending in date and setting week, could you instead combine them into a single ngModel? `[(ngModel)]="maintenance.week"`

Answer (score 0):

`(ngModelChange)` will emit a value of the `ngModel` that is if the value of the `ngModel` is `01-01-01` then the `$event` value will be `01-01-01`

Therefore to solve the problem change your code to `(ngModelChange)="maintenance.week = $event"`